# Which is correct, artifact or artefact?

Tags: word-choice

I am writing a book about illicit antiquities. Some of my resources spell this word, artefact; others, artifact. Is one right and the other wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Artefact is British, while Americans use artifact. So, depending on where you live, choose accordingly.

I found this information [here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/artefact).

Comment: @cobaltduck I was busy when I wrote it, but I did what you said.

Comment: SteveM's accepted answer to the question of which this is a duplicate is '_artefact_ is preferred in British English and _artifact_ is preferred in US English, but ... both are acceptable in either case.'